# What is the optimum way to combine linked rows of data in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where some of the records have been split across two rows (Bolus Type = Dual) and I am attempting to merge them based on there being at most 10 minutes between each. An example of data is here:

```
  Time         Bolus Type      Bolus Volume
1  0.0 Dual (normal part only)            1
2  0.2 Dual (square part only)            2
3  0.4                  Normal            3
4  0.6 Dual (normal part only)            2
5  0.8 Dual (square part only)            1
6  1.0                  Normal            3
```

The code I have currently got works but is too slow to run on some of my files (>30MB). I considered subsetting the data so that it only shows records with `Bolus Type` containing "Dual*" but then I don't know how I would go back to the original records to make the bolus type as having been combined.

```
#GENERATING SAMPLE DATA
a<-seq(0,1,length.out=6)
b<-c("Dual (normal part only)","Dual (square part only)","Normal","Dual (normal part only)","Dual (square part only)","Normal")
c<-c(1,2,3,2,1,3)
pt<-data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(pt)<-c('Time', 'Bolus Type','Bolus Volume')

countDual=0
countSquare=0
countNormal=0
min10<-0.3

#FIND EACH "DUAL NORMAL" PART
for(i in 1:nrow(pt)) {
  if(!is.na(pt$`Bolus Type`[i])&&pt$`Bolus Type`[i]=="Dual (normal part only)"){
    j<-i
    time_lim<-pt$`Time`[i]+min10

    found_square<-0

    #LOOK AT ROWS AHEAD OF I TO FIND NEAREST SQUARE WITHIN TIME PERIOD (0.2)
    while(pt$`Time`[j]<time_lim&&found_square!=1){
      if(!is.na(pt$`Bolus Type`[j])&&pt$`Bolus Type`[j]=="Dual (square part only)"){
        date<-pt[i,"Date"]
        time<-pt[i,"Time"]
        total_DB<-pt[i,"Bolus Volume"]+pt[j,"Bolus Volume"]

        #ADD DUAL TOTAL ROW AT BOTTOM
        row_num<-nrow(pt) + 1
        pt[row_num,"Time"] = time
        pt[row_num,"Bolus Type"] = "Dual (total)"
        pt[row_num,"Bolus Volume"] = total_DB


        found_square<-1 #Exit loop when finds first square within 10 minutes
        countDual<-countDual+1

        #MARK THE "LINKED" RECORDS
        pt[j,"Bolus Type"]<-"Dual (square part)"
        pt[i,"Bolus Type"]<-"Dual (normal part)"

      }
      j<-j+1
    }
  }
}

#MESSAGE OUT RESULTS
countNormalOnly<-sum(pt$`Bolus Type`[!is.na(pt$`Bolus Type`)]=="Dual (normal part only)")
countSquareOnly<-sum(pt$`Bolus Type`[!is.na(pt$`Bolus Type`)]=="Dual (square part only)")
message(paste(c("Dual:",countDual," Square only:",countSquareOnly," Normal only:",countNormalOnly)))
```

EDIT:
Desired output (as per current code output)

```
   Time         Bolus Type Bolus Volume
1  0.0 Dual (normal part)            1
2  0.2 Dual (square part)            2
3  0.4             Normal            3
4  0.6 Dual (normal part)            2
5  0.8 Dual (square part)            1
6  1.0             Normal            3
7  0.0       Dual (total)            3
8  0.6       Dual (total)            3
```

Comment: show your desired output data.frame

Comment: The desired output adds a row for each merge it has managed to do and also edits the bolus type to show it is part of a combination (e.g. square part only --> square part)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

pt_joined <-
  pt %>%
  filter(`Bolus Type` %like% 'Dual') %>%
  mutate(Index = cumsum(`Bolus Type` %like% 'normal')) %>%
  group_by(Index) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = max(Time - lag(Time), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(time_diff <= .2) %>%
  mutate(`Bolus Type` = str_remove_all(`Bolus Type`, " only")) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-time_diff)

pt_dual <- pt_joined %>%
  group_by(`Index`) %>%
  summarize(
    Time = min(Time),
    `Bolus Type` = 'Dual',
    `Bolus Volume` = sum(`Bolus Volume`)
  )

pt_new <-
  pt %>%
  left_join(pt_joined, by = c("Time", "Bolus Volume")) %>%
  mutate(`Bolus Type` =
           ifelse(is.na(`Bolus Type.y`), `Bolus Type.x`, `Bolus Type.y`)) %>%
  select(-contains(".")) %>%
  bind_rows(pt_dual) %>% select(-Index)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm quite new to R. Please could you help me with this error that I get from your code:
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "%like%"

Comment: My apologies, that's a function from the `data.table` package, I thought it was from `dplyr`.  Just install `data.table` and add it to the list of libraries at the top.